# Using Function from a class in API Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to set some data in an API class by calling a function from another class.

1. Why the 'main' has error while 'Classes' works? How and where I should define it?
   Error: a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field
2. How do I can get the ID which has passed in URL to use in my class?

This is my code:

```
public class InformationController : ApiController
{
    Classes main = new Classes();

    Information[] Information = new Information[]
    {
        new Information { Info_ID = 2, fullName = main.getFullname("2"), },
    };

    public IEnumerable<Information> GetAllInformation()
    {
        return Information;
    }

    public Information GetInformationById(int id)
    {
        var information = Information.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Info_ID == id);
        if (information == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return information;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Information> GetInformationByCategory(string category)
    {
        return Information.Where(
            (p) => string.Equals(p.std_nextClass, category,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Why the main doesn't work?"? Are you getting an error when calling `main.getFullname("2")`? How does the implementation of `Classes` look?

Comment: [Web API Tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+web+api+tutorial) <= start there. Trying to learn a new platform by trial and error and posting on [so] for answers in that process is just not a good way to go about it.

Comment: The 'main' is an instance of a class to call non-static functions.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `Classes` ?

Comment: I think, you defined the "getFullname" method as static, you should remove static keyword

Comment: public string getFullname(string ID)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Classes.ConnectionString);
...
}

Comment: What errors did you receive?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're describing.  Please indicate the *exact* error message, the *exact* line of code which produces that error, and any relevant code for demonstrating the error.

Comment: Error: a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field

Comment: @NavidAbyazi: You're being too vague.  Try to understand that *we can't see your screen or the rest of your code*.  We don't know what line is producing the error.  We don't know the rest of your class definitions.  Etc.  Please provide information about the problem.

Comment: string fullname = "";
            SqlCommand cmd_fullName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Info_ID, Info_Fname + ' ' + Info_Lname AS 'fullName' FROM Information WHERE Info_ID = @Info_ID", conn);
            cmd_fullName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Info_ID", ID);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr_fullName = cmd_fullName.ExecuteReader();

Comment: if (sdr_fullName.HasRows)
                while (sdr_fullName.Read())
                    if (sdr_fullName["fullName"].ToString() != "")
                        fullname = sdr_fullName["fullName"].ToString();
            sdr_fullName.Close();
            conn.Close();

            return fullname;

Comment: Could you also help about my second question? Getting ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try initialize the array in the constructor:

```c#
public class InformationController : ApiController
{
    private Classes main = new Classes();

    private Information[] Information;

    public InformationController()
    {
        Information = new Information[]
        {
            new Information { Info_ID = 2, fullName = main.getFullname("2"), },
        };
    }
  /// the rest of your code...
```